# Converting Java application to JApplet for online access

Tags: java, swing, jframe, japplet

I have a difficult dilemma. I implemented a java application using Netbeans while implementing it I used JFrame and now I want to convert it to JApplet so that it can essentially function as a web service. I have lots of classes and I tried Changing JFrame to Japplet as directed in some solutions on this site but then new errors arise because of that... for example ... exit on close method not defined ... pack not defined and so on.

Could anybody give me a better solution.

Thanks a lot 
Any help appreciated

Comment: If you have a specific problem, paste some code. In short, you'll have to remove all the methods that aren't used in Java applets.

Comment: @Jivings : the problem is Netbeans has inserted many methods there that I am not even aware of ... and as I said I have lots of class so is there any way I can achieve this without rewriting a large amount of code

Comment: *"it can essentially function as a web service."* Launch the `JFrame` from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) and you'll have far fewer deployment and maintenance problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ..exit on close method not defined ...

An applet is a guest in a web page and might share a JVM with other applets.  Exiting the VM is like 'burning down the guest house'.  Instead call `showDocument(thanksForUsingUrl)`.

> ..pack not defined and so on.

`validate()`